# Installing Nose into my home directory (without sudo)?

Tags: installation, home-directory, python

Is it possible to install Nose (http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.1/) into a subdirectory of my home
directory on a Linux machine?  (I'm not on the sudoers list for that
machine.)  If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

But I didn't mention that (because I'm not on the sudoers list), I also did a custom Python install.  When I installed correctly following [Crast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244393/crast)'s instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278028/how-do-i-work-around-this-problem-creating-a-virtualenv-environment-with-a-custom/2278059#2278059, I was able to install nose using that version of Python.

**Update**: I didn't notice until now that when I actually run `nosetests`, I get:

```
$ nosetests
bash: /home/dspitzer/apps/bin/nosetests: /usr/local/bin/python2.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I'll try reinstalling with the `--root` option  as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: I suggest you to try running a trivial python script that does nothing and see what happens. I strongly suspect that you have a broken python install.

Answer (score -1):

Also most setup.py scripts support a custom root directory setting.
So you can use them like:

```
python setup.py install --root <a subdirectory of your home directory>
```

Having that subdirectory in **PYTHONPATH**, you shall be able to get access to modules that you installed there.

Comment: I ran `python setup.py install --root ~/apps/nose-0.11.1/` and it seemed to install correctly.  I found `nosetests` in ~/apps/nose-0.11.1/home/dspitzer/apps/bin/, but when I run it I get the same error: "bash: ./nosetests: /usr/local/bin/python2.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Comment: With such --root the nosetests script shall get installed into ~/apps/nose-0.11.1/bin, the nose python package - into ~/apps/nose-0.11.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages. Running it from there gives an error. This is obvious - no nose in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages. Running it like "PYTHONPATH=~/apps/nose-0.11.1/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ ./nosetests" when being in ~/apps/nose-0.11.1/bin makes it work as expected. Before doing this I've removed the nose package from my system (Slackware Linux 13.0) so it wouldn't interfere into my experiment.